# Django admin returns 404 with tinymce

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, tinymce

I'm getting 404 with Django admin and tinymce

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS= [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Blogpost)
class BlogpostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('blog/tiny.js',)
```

**js**

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);
script.onload=function ()
{
    tinymce.init(
    {
        selector: '#id_content',
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Amine Messaoudi but the problem still exists, should i change my variable type to "HTML" currently its a text field in my models

Comment: Have you include `tinymce` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: No, it is a cdn link and js file and setting in admin, should i??

Comment: Are you using [django-tinymce-lite](https://pypi.org/project/django-tinymce4-lite/)? It might help

Comment: @KhAliqKHan did you put `tiny.js` in static folder ?

Comment: yes i made a folder inside static/blog/js. oh ok i forgot to mention "/js" that path, Ok so that was the reason. Thank Bro @AmineMessaoudi  :)